# Magento 2.2.7. Cart subtotals not showing taxes

Tags: magento2

According to the configuration of the screenshot, the taxes are still not showing on the cart subtotals. Any ideas why I am missing anyway?

[image]

Comment: did you clean the config-cache? are you in the correct scope?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7801

Comment: Yes, the whole cache has been cleaned and flushed; I also applied the changes on the respective store view scope; I'm implementing Magento 2.2.7

Comment: it's been mentioned on the GitHub link: "then i had to change component from Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total to Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total for grand-total in file checkout_cart_index.xml to make it work". How exactly??